# how to pass arguments and parameters in json web service?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, json

```
-(void)gettop10button
{   
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appabn.com/iphone/files/api/api.php?q=helo_users&u_id=5&page=1"];  // web api link

    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

in the last of the link we see that page=1 , i have more than 10 pages . 
    so how can i pass a variable/parameter/argument , so i can increment page no. 
    Thanks in advance '`int page;
    page++;`

```
can perform like as .
```

in the last of the link we see that page=1 , i have more than 10 pages . 
    so how can i pass a variable/parameter/argument , so i can increment page no. 
    Thanks in advance '`int page;
    page++;`

can perform like as .

```
if(connection)
{
    webData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}   
[JustConfesstable reloadData];
```

Comment: NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appabn.com/iphone/files/api/api.php?q=helo_users&u_id=5&page=1"];  // web api link

i want to pass argument in place of page

Comment: Use another number other than `1`?

Comment: For URL parameter use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://appabn.com/iphone/files/api/api.php?q=helo_users&u_id=5&page=%d", page];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so simple. I am still amazed which part of the code you are not getting. You just have to take one variable (say `pageNo`) of type `int` and then provide it the default value `1`.
You just have to increment the `pageNo` (using `pageNo++`) to get the next page value and then you have to create string for URL with `pageNo` and then simply pass it to URL using the method called `URLWithString` of class `NSURL`.

---

**Translation of all the above description in 4 easy steps using Objective-C :**

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://appabn.com/iphone/files/api/api.php?q=helo_users&u_id=5&page=%d",pageNo];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];  // web api link
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```